# VS Code does not expand variables in its settings

Tags: environment-variables, visual-studio-code, expansion

Is it the expected behaviour that VS Code does not expand variables in its settings?

My example: I need to configure *Remote.SSH: Config File* to point to a file relative to my home directory. Verbatim values work:

- `C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/config_vs_code`
- `C:\Users\myusername\.ssh\config_vs_code`

I would certainly expect that [variable expansion](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) should work but it does not. These values are not functional:

- `${userHome}/.ssh/config_vs_code`
- `${env:UserProfile}/.ssh/config_vs_code`
- `${userHome}\.ssh\config_vs_code`
- `${env:UserProfile}\.ssh\config_vs_code`

`${env:UserProfile}` expands correctly in my PowerShell.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different way how to use variables in VS Code settings?

Comment: It looks like VS Code simply does not expand variables in its settings. Stack Overflow: [How can I use "~" or "$HOME" in VisualStudioCode settings on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67466293/320437)

Answer (score 0):

Despite that this is an older question, for the sake of completeness: This now works with version 1.79.0 (maybe also earlier) of VS code. At least I was able to successfully use `${env:USERPROFILE)` in the settings.json file, running VSC at Windows 10. This seems to be case-insensitive, `UserProfile` did work, too.